# what's the difference between "correctly-sized packet" vs. "correct-size packet."

Tags: american-english, compound-adjectives

The sentence is the following:

> [...] It allows you to request transfers of any size. Internally, the
> request will be divided up into **correctly-sized** packets. [...]

Sometimes I read adjectives written like this, but I don't really understand why shouldn't I use the simpler version 'correct-size' packets? Is this simpler version valid? Has the same meaning?

I don't know how to search for such questions on the internet. Any material regarding those compound adjects would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: The constructions both seem legal, correctly formed,  as you imply. English is **usage**-driven. And sometimes, 'wrong' (using words 'wrongly'; using abnormal grammar) usages take root. Idioms arise. Candidates that weren't words _become_ words. Neologisms arise. You have to monitor the situation. Here, if dictionaries don't list logical-looking candidates, raw Google searches and Google ngram searches can help. What have you tried?

Comment: [For instance](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=correct-size+mask%2Ccorrect+size+mask%2Ccorrectly-sized+mask%2Ccorrectly+sized+mask&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccorrect%20size%20mask%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccorrectly%20sized%20mask%3B%2Cc0) (Google ngrams): I'd say you have a free choice.

Comment: I think there's a slightly different meaning between 'correct-sized packets' and 'correctly-sized packets'. For me 'correct-sized packets' implies that there are pre-made physical packets (such as jiffy bags) into which the product is placed whereas 'correctly-sized packets' suggests either that the packets are virtual (as in financial transactions or data transmission) or that, if physical packages are being used, the packages are being made up around the goods to be dispatched. It could be just me, though, I'd be interested in other people's views.

Comment: I deleted an earlier comment similar to that of @BoldBen when I noticed that the question concerns data packets. More generally, a "correctly-sized" packet is one that is made for a specific job, but a packet "of the correct size" is one you select from several available, that is the most suitable for the job. Which broadly, is what BB says. I would never say 'correct-size'.

Comment: @WeatherVane Maybe I should have provided more context. 'correctly-sized' seemed more correct to me but I couldn't say the reason. Now it makes more sense for me. Thank you all.